# .NET C# Developer on Mac

Tags: .net, macos, ubuntu

Can I be fully .NET C# (Especially ASP.NET MVC) on Mac (Mac OS) or on Linux Ubuntu OS developer? If yes, is it alternatives for Visual Studio?

Comment: Nitpick: Macs are computer that can run Windows so you can do whatever you want. For OS X the answer is: depends.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Using Visual Studio Code and Asp.NET Core you can develop cross-platform applications on your Mac. Here's are a some helpful links:

- [MSDN Magazine August 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/mt767698)
- a sample project [including MVC](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/getting-started-with-asp-net-5-and-visual-studio-code-on-a-mac.html)

Answer (score 0):

So far, I can not find solution to run Visual Studio or developing ASP.Net (MVC also) at mac.

You need windows on your Mac. I use parallel Desktop, similar like Virtual Box or VM Ware.

You may also use BootCamp, the stability depends on your Mac Version.

My Mac is not so stable using bootCamp. But maybe you are lucky enough if your mac is stable to run BootCamp.